# Error Accessing Array in MIPS assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I made this code for finding LCM of two numbers. It is the starting chunk which is having problems. I tried to find the problem but couldn't figure it out. It is giving me error of unaligned address and other exceptions when I try to Load word or Store word. Here is the code:

```
.data

user: .asciiz "enter first number\n"
user2: .asciiz "enter second number\n"

array1: .space 500
array2: .space 500
array3: .space 500

.text

main:

la $a0,user
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall

move $s0,$v0

la $a0,user2
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall

move $s1,$v0

li $t0,0
li $t1,0
li $t2,2    
li $t3,3
li $t4,0
li $t5,5
li $t6,7
li $t7,0
li $t8,0
li $t9,0
li $s8,0

la $t8,array1
la $t9,array2

j Loop1



Loop1:

div $s0,$t2

mflo $s2
mfhi $s3 # remainder

beq $s2,1,Loop2

xor $s5,$s3,$0

beq $s5,1,Odd3

add $t4,$t7,$t8

sw $t2,0($t4)  # error

addi $t7,$t7,4


j Loop1
```

Regards

Comment: Please mention and add a tag saying which assembler you use (probably spim or gas)

Comment: Can I have your email address? My code is messing up so I would like to send it to you. If you like to see the code here, I will past here but the code is very lengthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it complains about unaligned address, then you should go look why it's unaligned. Assemblers are typically smart enough to align data as appropriate, but you are using the `.space` directive which doesn't have any type (and hence alignment) information. By chance your strings make the arrays unaligned. You can fix this by manually adding a `.align 2` directive before `array1`.